# Function is not creating inside Azure function App using ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I am trying to deploy the Azure Function App inside this one function using with Azure blob trigger using the ARM template.

I am able to deploy the function app and it's up and running but the function inside is not getting created.

First I created one function app and inside that create one function. I am copying all the files for that function in blob storage and providing the ****init**.py** and **function.json** file in **appsetting**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.10.61.36676",
      "templateHash": "2440974564149075183"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "test-function-name",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Azure Function app."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "appInsightsLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for Application Insights"
      }
    },
    "functionWorkerRuntime": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "python",
      "allowedValues": [
        "dotnet",
        "node",
        "python",
        "java"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The language worker runtime to load in the function app."
      }
    },
    "linuxFxVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "python|3.9",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Required for Linux app to represent runtime stack in the format of 'runtime|runtimeVersion'. For example: 'python|3.9'"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "hostingPlanName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "applicationInsightsName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "storageAccountName": "[format('{0}azfunctions', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
      "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "Storage"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Y1",
        "tier": "Dynamic",
        "size": "Y1",
        "family": "Y"
      },
      "properties": {
        "computeMode": "Dynamic",
        "reserved": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('appInsightsLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "[format('hidden-link:{0}', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('applicationInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      },
      "kind": "web"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp,linux",
      "properties": {
        "reserved": true,
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[parameters('linuxFxVersion')]",
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('functionAppName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', variables('storageAccountName'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', variables('storageAccountName'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "[parameters('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
              "value": "true"
            }
          ]
        },
        "apiDefinition": 
        {
            "value": [
            {
              "name": "test-trigger-function",
              "type": "function",
              "properties": {
                  "script_href": "blob_url/folder/__init__.py",
                  "script_root_path_href": "blob_url/folder/",
                  "config_href": "blob_url/folder/function.json",
                  "config": {},
                  "language": "python",
                  "isDisabled": false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to create one function app with operating system as Linux and runtime as Python3.9 and inside that one function which can take the older function configuration and files from the blob storage.

I am able to create the function app shown below.
[image: Function app in Azure]

**Now I want to create the function inside the function app shown below.**
[image: Function inside the function app]

I tried to follow the documentation but I am not able to figure out how to create function inside the function app.

Comment: Can you explain what is the current requirement in a detailed way? @Ravi kant Gautam

Comment: @Jahnavi I have updated my question with more details, could you please go through it?

Comment: Are you trying to create a blob triggered function or any other function? @Ravi kant Gautam

Comment: yes correct blob trigger function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Function is not creating inside Azure function App using ARM Template: -

After a workaround on your requirement, I found an approach to add a function inside the function App using [`"Microsoft.Web/sites/functions"`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites/functions?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) resource type as follows.

***Code in ARM (Json) format:***

```bash
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.19.5.34762",
      "templateHash": "1037450281519309886"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "functionAppName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "newxxx",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the Azure Function app."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the storage account that you wish to use."
      }
    },
    "storageAccountType": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Standard_LRS",
        "Standard_GRS",
        "Standard_RAGRS"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Storage Account type"
      }
    },
    "blobContainerName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the blob container that you wish to use."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    },
    "appInsightsLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for Application Insights"
      }
    },
    "functionWorkerRuntime": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "python",
      "allowedValues": [
        "dotnet",
        "node",
        "python",
        "java"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The language worker runtime to load in the function app."
      }
    },
    "functionName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the function that you wish to create."
      }
    },
    "linuxFxVersion": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "python|3.9",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Required for Linux app to represent runtime stack in the format of 'runtime|runtimeVersion'. For example: 'python|3.9'"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "hostingPlanName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "applicationInsightsName": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
    "storageAccountName_var": "[format('{0}azfunctions', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
      "name": "'storage${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
      },
      "kind": "Storage"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "[variables('hostingPlanName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Y1",
        "tier": "Dynamic",
        "size": "Y1",
        "family": "Y"
      },
      "properties": {
        "computeMode": "Dynamic",
        "reserved": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Insights/components",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02",
      "name": "[variables('applicationInsightsName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('appInsightsLocation')]",
      "tags": {
        "[format('hidden-link:{0}', resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('applicationInsightsName')))]": "Resource"
      },
      "properties": {
        "Application_Type": "web"
      },
      "kind": "web"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp,linux",
      "properties": {
        "reserved": true,
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]",
        "siteConfig": {
          "linuxFxVersion": "[parameters('linuxFxVersion')]",
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
              "value": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', parameters('functionAppName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
            },
            {
              "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', variables('storageAccountName_var'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName_var')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[format('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};EndpointSuffix={1};AccountKey={2}', variables('storageAccountName_var'), environment().suffixes.storage, listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName_var')), '2019-06-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
              "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(parameters('functionAppName'))]"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~4"
            },
            {
              "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
              "value": "[parameters('functionWorkerRuntime')]"
            },
            {
              "name": "SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT",
              "value": "true"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('hostingPlanName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "tags": "sds",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Premium_LRS"
      },
      "kind": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
      "apiVersion": "2021-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), 'default')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}/{2}', parameters('storageAccountName'), 'default', format('{0}default{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')))]",
      "properties": {
        "publicAccess": "None"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices', parameters('storageAccountName'), 'default')]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions",
      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('functionAppName'), format('{0}', parameters('functionName')))]",
      "properties": {
        "config": {
          "bindings": [
            {
              "name": "myBlob",
              "type": "blobTrigger",
              "direction": "in",
              "path": "[format('default/{0}/{{name}}', parameters('blobContainerName'))]",
              "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
            }
          ],
          "disabled": false
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers', parameters('storageAccountName'), 'default', format('{0}default{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('blobContainerName')))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

***Code in bicep file format:***

```bash
@description('The name of the Azure Function app.')
param  functionAppName  string = 'newjappsun'
@description('The name of the storage account that you wish to use.')
param  storageAccountName  string = 'latestjstore'
@description('Storage Account type')
@allowed([
'Standard_LRS'
'Standard_GRS'
'Standard_RAGRS'
])
param  storageAccountType  string = 'Standard_LRS'
@description('The name of the blob container that you wish to use.')
param  blobContainerName  string = 'new'
@description('Location for all resources.')
param  location  string = resourceGroup().location
@description('Location for Application Insights')
param  appInsightsLocation  string = resourceGroup().location
@description('The language worker runtime to load in the function app.')
@allowed([
'dotnet'
'node'
'python'
'java'
])
param  functionWorkerRuntime  string = 'python'
@description('The name of the function that you wish to create.')
param  functionName  string = 'newfuncj'
@description('Required for Linux app to represent runtime stack in the format of \'runtime|runtimeVersion\'. For example: \'python|3.9\'')
param  linuxFxVersion  string = 'python|3.9'
var  hostingPlanName = functionAppName
var  applicationInsightsName = functionAppName
resource  hostingPlan  'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
name: hostingPlanName
location: location
sku: {
name: 'Y1'
tier: 'Dynamic'
size: 'Y1'
family: 'Y'
}
properties: {
computeMode: 'Dynamic'
reserved: true
}
}
resource  applicationInsights  'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
name: applicationInsightsName
location: appInsightsLocation
tags: {
'hidden-link:${resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites',  applicationInsightsName)}': 'Resource'
}
properties: {
Application_Type: 'web'
}
kind: 'web'
}
resource  functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
name: functionAppName
location: location
kind: 'functionapp,linux'
properties: {
reserved: true
serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
siteConfig: {
linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion
appSettings: [
{
name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
value: reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components',  functionAppName),  '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey
}
{
name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',  storageAccountName),  '2019-06-01').keys[0].value}'
}
{
name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
value: 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${storageAccountName};EndpointSuffix=${environment().suffixes.storage};AccountKey=${listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts',  storageAccountName),  '2019-06-01').keys[0].value}'
}
{
name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE'
value: toLower(functionAppName)
}
{
name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
value: '~4'
}
{
name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
value: functionWorkerRuntime
}
{
name: 'SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT'
value: 'true'
}
]
}
}
}
resource  storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-08-01' = {
name: storageAccountName
location: location
sku: {
name: 'Standard_LRS'
}
kind: 'StorageV2'
}
resource  blobService 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices@2021-06-01' = {
name: 'default'
parent: storageAccount
}
resource  storageAccountName_default_blobContainer  'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers@2019-06-01' = {
name: '${storageAccountName}default${blobContainerName}'
parent: blobService
properties: {
publicAccess: 'None'
}
}
resource  functionAppName_function 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions@2018-02-01' = {
parent: functionApp
name: '${functionName}'
properties: {
config: {
bindings: [
{
name: 'myBlob'
type: 'blobTrigger'
direction: 'in'
path: 'default/${blobContainerName}/{name}'
connection: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
}
]
disabled: false
}
}
dependsOn: [
storageAccountName_default_blobContainer
]
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Refer [article](https://www.gyanblog.com/azure/azure-arm-template-how-create-function-blob-trigger-sendgrid-deployment/#azure-arm-template) by @GyanBlog for more detailed structure of the template.

Comment: When running the above code, are you getting this error? @RavikantGautam

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am able to fix the error and I am able to create the resource.

But now I want to pass the Python code to the created function using the ARM template, I have python code and other files which I created manually for different function.

Comment: Using bicep, you want to do that? @RavikantGautam

Comment: I am not fluent in the bicep but I can manage in bicep as well but usually, I work in ARM template.

Comment: could you please help me with the above comment?

Comment: Can you elaborate the issue? @RavikantGautam

Comment: sure
I have an existing Azure function app and function inside that running on Python stack and it's working fine. I can install the external dependencies as well and it's getting triggered with Blob and working as expected.
Now I want to create one Azure function app and function inside with the above existing function Python code and external dependencies using an ARM template.
So my output will be a new Azure function with existing code and dependencies.

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help explaining this issue in more detail.

Comment: Can you check this [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/421275/creating-azure-python-function-app-hosted-on-consu) works for you? @RavikantGautam